# Getting object from DB returns empty object or app crashes

Tags: android, sqlite

In my DB manager class I have a method to retrieve selected_group with group_db and trip_db parameters.

```
public Selected_Group get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(int trip_id, int group_id)
{
    open_readable();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.Table_Names.TABLE_NAME_SELECTED_GROUPS, null, "trip_id="+trip_id+"&group_id="+group_id, null, null, null, null);
    int sg_id = 0;
    int sg_trip_id = 0;
    int sg_group_id = 0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        sg_id = cursor.getInt(0);
        sg_trip_id = cursor.getInt(1);
        sg_group_id = cursor.getInt(2);
    }

    Selected_Group sg = new Selected_Group(sg_id, sg_trip_id, sg_group_id);
    cursor.close();
    close();
    return sg;
}
```

However in this case the cursor skips the entire `while` loop and I'm receiving a Selected_Group with initiated values, i.e. _id = 0.

So I tried it this way:

```
public Selected_Group get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(int trip_id, int group_id)
{
    open_readable();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.Table_Names.TABLE_NAME_SELECTED_GROUPS, null, "trip_id="+trip_id+"&group_id="+group_id, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int sg_id = cursor.getInt(0);
    int sg_trip_id = cursor.getInt(1);
    int sg_group_id = cursor.getInt(2);
    Selected_Group sg = new Selected_Group(sg_id, sg_trip_id, sg_group_id);
    cursor.close();
    close();
    return sg;
}
```

In this case the app crashes with the following error message:

```
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.mycompany.myapp.tasks.Task_DB_Manager.get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(Task_DB_Manager.java:542)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.mycompany.myapp.activities.Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.onClick(Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.java:263)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I checked with debugger and all the parameters are being passed correctly. SQLite Browser shows that I have a record with these parameters in corresponding table.

The table was constructed in DB_Helper class:

```
// Create table selected groups
String create_table_selected_groups = "CREATE TABLE "+Constants.Table_Names.TABLE_NAME_SELECTED_GROUPS+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"+
            ", trip_id INTEGER, group_id INTEGER);";
db.execSQL(create_table_selected_groups);
```

So why is it not being returned? What's the problem with this code?

Comment: 1) Replace & with AND

2) You should use Cursor::getColumnIndex for getting indexes 

3) You shouldn't have underscores in class and method names

4) Opening brace must not be on the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator works on binary numbers and has greater associativity than `=`.

What you want is `AND`:

```
"trip_id="+trip_id+" AND group_id="+group_id
```

Comment: Thanks! looks like `AND` along with using `Cursor::getColumnIndex` from the comment to the question worked!